# Categorizing ideals in the polynomial ring with real or complex coefficients?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Is the ideal $(x^2 + 3x + 7)$ maximal, prime or radical in $\mathbb{R}[x]$?

How about in $\mathbb{C}[x]$?

For $\mathbb{R}[x]$, I first want to try and show it is or is not maximal, if it is not, then show it is prime, and if not, show it is radical. My instinct is to say that it is a prime ideal, but I do not know how to go about and do this.

Comment: Hint: If a second-degree polynomial can be factored, then it has a zero (and vice versa).

Comment: Hint: What does the quadratic formula tell you?

Comment: That it has roots $- \frac{9 \pm \sqrt{-19}}{2}$. i.e. the polynomial has no roots in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ and so is irreducible in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ but not in $\mathbb{C}[x]$ as $\sqrt{-19} = \sqrt{19} i$.

Answer (score 2):

the discriminant of the polynomial $f=x^2+3x+7$ is $3^2-4\cdot7 = -19$. since this is not the square of any element in $\mathbb{R}$, $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{R}$.

as $\mathbb{R}[x]$ is a principal ideal domain, irreducibles are prime and primes are maximal. so proving this is the trickiest bit of the problem. but perhaps you are intended simply to quote these well-known results?

suppose for any $g \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ we have $g^n=hf$ for $n \ge 1$. then $f|g$ so $g=h_1f$ and $g \in (f)$, so $(f)$ is radical

Comment: I think if this was the route I went down, I would want to show that irreducibles are prime and primes are maximal in $\mathbb{R}$. I'm sure I can find this, though are there any hints to thinking through this?

Comment: have you experience of the "Euclidean division algorithm to compute the greatest common factor of two positive integers? a similar procedure works for polynomials in a single variable over a field. that might be a good starting point

Comment: How about:

Suppose (f) is not maximal. Then there is an ideal $I$ with $(f) \subsetneq I \subsetneq \mathbb{R}[x]$. Since $\mathbb{R}[x]$ is a principal ideal domain, $I = (q)$ for some polynomial $(q) \in \mathbb{R}[x]$. 

Since $(f) \subsetneq I$, then we can write $f=qr$ for some $r \in \mathbb{R}[x]$. Since $f$ is irreducible, and $q$ cannot be a unit (as $I \neq \mathbb{R}[x]$), $r$ must be a unit. Thus, we can write $q=fr^{-1}$, and so $q \in (f)$ as $(f)$ is an ideal. This contradicts $(f) \subsetneq I$ and so $(f) = I$. Hence $(f)$ is a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{R}[x].$

Comment: What would be the best way to tackle the problem with $(f) \subset \mathbb{C}[x]$

Comment: your argument irreducible implies maximal looks  sound (+1). as you noted in a previous comment $f$ is reducible over $\mathbb{C}$ so cannot be prime. is it radical?

Comment: Suppose $q(x) \in \mathbb{C}[x]$ but $q(x) \notin (f)$. Then $q \neq a.f + b$ where $a \in \mathbb{C}[x]$ and $b \in (f)$, because if it were, then $q \in (f).$ So, $q = a.f + c$ for some $a,c \in \mathbb{C}[x]$, but $c \notin (f).$ Suppose $q^n \in (f).$ $q^n = (af + c)^n = a^nf^n + ca^{n-1}f^{n-1} + ... + c^{n-1}af + c^n.$ Each of the terms is in $(f)$ automatically from the definition of an ideal, except for $c^n$. Hence, $q^n \in (f)$ if and only if $c^n \in (f)$, but $c \notin (f)$, so $(f)$ cannot be radical, since $q = af + c \notin (f)$.

Comment: i think you may need to clarify your thought here.  in a commutative ring an ideal $J$ is radical iff $x^n \in J \to x \in J$. think first  of $\mathbb{Z}$. the radical  of an ideal generated by $\prod_i p_i^{a_i}$ (for $p_i$ primes and $a_i \gt 0$ ) is that generated by $\prod_i p_i$ - a quadratfrei integer. in the PID $\mathbb{C}[x]$ we have that $f$ splits into a product of two degree-1 monomials, which are distinct primes.

Comment: ok, so since we can split $f$ into two degree-1 monomials $a$ and $b$, and $a$ and $b$ are prime in $\mathbb{C}[x]$ (is this simply because they are monomials?), then the product of these two primes, generates a radical ideal in $\mathbb{C}[x]$. This is $ab=f$, and hence $(f)$ is radical. Is there a way to prove that the product of primes is a radical ideal?

Comment: if a prime $p$ divides $x^n$  then you can show by a method of descent that $p$ divides $x$. for $x^{n+1} \in\mathfrak{p} \Rightarrow (x\in\mathfrak{p})\lor (x^n\in\mathfrak{p})$ (definition of prime ideal)

Comment: and yes, monomials are prime (over a field) by an argument based on degree.;

Comment: apologies btw, just realized i have been writing "monomial" where what was meant was a polynomial of degree 1. logic circuit fail (LCF).